# Why is R removing some residuals and how to avoid it?

Tags: r

I am creating linear models in R and testing them for model assumptions.

I noticed that when I create my models, R removes some residuals, giving this:

```
(2 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

This prevents me from checking the relationship between the independent variable and the residuals and any further analysis because of the different lengths for x and y.

edit:
[image: when I create the linear model, 2 residuals are removed so I cannot correlate the residuals with the independent variable from the dataset]

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are there missing values or NA in the dataset?

Comment: Hi @Dave2e, I checked it and there aren't any missing values or NA in the dataset. I even used the na.omit multiple times to double check

Comment: Hi Justine. That message appears when it that you have two missing values in `x` or `y` columns on different rows in your dataset. Basically, if you have 10 `x` data points paired with 8 `y` data points (where 2 `y` data points are missing or NA), the linear model cannot use the two `x` data points that doesn't have a `y` value beside it. Check again with `which(is.na(dataset$x))` and `which(is.na(dataset$x))` to find missing values. Or, try the linear model again using `lm(data = tidyr::drop_na(dataset, x, y), y ~ x)`. It would get rid of the message, but you'll have the same results.

Comment: `dataset[!complete.cases(dataset), ]` will also show you all rows with any missing values.

Comment: @Dave2e I added a screenshot of the problem. Also it may be important that hamTransSub is a SPDF

Comment: @CalumYou thanks! I just tried it, but I don't think it works because the dataset is a spatial data frame

Comment: @LC-datascientist yeah, I am trying to correlate the residuals from the model I created with the independent variable, but whenever I run the model, 2 residuals are taken out (I added a photo to the post) so I can't correlate the residuals (178 data points) and the independent variable (180 data points)

Comment: My typo in my comment earlier: The second which() command is supposed to be `which(is.na(dataset$y))` to see which `y` row has missing data. Anyway, there are many ways to check (I like @CalumYou's suggestion better, actually).

Comment: @Justine Okay, I think I know a solution. `model_5$residuals` should have names that correspond to the row names in the `hamTransSub` dataset (default is the row numbers). You can find which rows weren't used in the model by finding the row names that are missing from `names(model_5$residuals)`. You can remove those from the independent variable to have them match for the correlation (or merge or inner join them by row names).

Comment: @LC-datascientist awesome, I'll try it. Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

R isn't *removing residuals* when you run `lm()`. Rather, it cannot *create residuals* for samples that have any missing data in the model (nor actually use them in the analysis). Therefore, the `summary(model_5)` output notifies you that some samples (observations) cannot be used (i.e., are deleted).

To run a correlation between the residuals and the independent variable when there is a difference in their lengths, and when for some reason we cannot find the missing data to remove from the dataset (e.g., if `dataset[!complete.cases(dataset), ]` isn't working), we first need to figure another way to find which observations are kept/removed in the model. We may be able to rely on the observation ID or the dataset's row names for this.

Example

```r
# sample data
set.seed(12345)
dataset <- data.frame(indep_var = c(NA, rnorm(9)), dep_var = c(rnorm(9), NA))
dataset$index <- rownames(dataset)

# model residuals
resid <- lm(data=dataset, dep_var ~ indep_var)$residuals
dataset.resid <- data.frame(index = names(resid), resid)

# join or match the residuals and the variables by their observation identifier
cor.data <- dplyr::inner_join(dataset.resid, dataset, by = "index")

# correlation analysis
cor.test(~ resid + indep_var, cor.data)
```

Note that `names(resid)` are the row names of the observations used in the model from `dataset`. Any unused `rownames(dataset)` or observations/rows from `dataset` (due to missingness) will not be included in `names(resid)`.